# How can I obtain the close button drawable from the SearchView?

Tags: android

How can I get the drawable used by the SearchView?
Looking at the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/SearchView.java) I can see it uses `R.styleable.SearchView_closeIcon`:

```
mCloseButton.setImageDrawable(a.getDrawable(R.styleable.SearchView_closeIcon));
```

Is it possible to get the drawable instance so I can use it in my code?